# Debian Squeeze with RAID 10

Tags: raid, raid5, raid10, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Debian Squeeze on a server and set it up with RAID 5, or RAID 10 if possible (4 disks). I'm having difficulty finding **detailed** instructions on how to do this. I'm hoping that someone could help me out with instructions on setting up RAID on a linux box.

Comment: Why was this voted down 1? Are people no longer allowed to ask questions when they don't know something?

Comment: As it says in our FAQ this site is for professional sysadmins, who done their homework and know how to do the basics. I didn't downvote you though.

Comment: Open the controller's BIOS and follow the instructions found in the controller's manual.

Comment: Probably because asking for **detailed** (i.e. do it all for me) instructions is pretty much the ServerFault equivalent of "plz give me teh codez". I'm guessing you mean software RAID? Typically you'd install to one disk, then create the array in the OS's disk management to mirror it across the rest of the disks.

Comment: I didn't down vote the question, but essentially you have provided no details of your setup and what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to do hardware or software RAID?  What controller (make, model)?  Either way, yes, RAID-10 on 4 disks is possible.  If you're using hardware RAID, you would first setup the RAID-10 array sing the (manufacturer) provided configuration software, and then install Debian as usual.  If doing software RAID, I _think_ you can setup the RAID volumes during the install when partitioning the disks .  I know you can with SuSE, but I've not installed Debian.

Comment: @Kendall, you can setup RAID during the install.  It is really easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to setup the software RAID.  Do a standard install, up to the point where you see the disk partitioning.  Choose manual, setup a small partition (1GB) at the start of a drive or two the /boot partition, which cannot be on a RAID5/10.  Create partitions for the rest of the space on each drive and set it for RAID usage.  From the menu choose the option to configure the raid, then configure the RAID.  Once you are done configuring the RAID you should probably setup LVM on top of that so you can easily partition things out as needed.

Comment: On the other hand he could use BTRFS as it has the software RAID and LVM features included without additional software. But he didn't even state what he wants to do with the RAID, if it is for production, and ...